# Django CMS - Copy relations in custom plugin not working

Tags: django-cms

I have a problem with copy_relations after publishing a page. 
I have a plugin with additional model. This model has ForeignKey to my plugin.

```
class InfContactForm(CMSPlugin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        self.inf_contact_form.all().delete()
        for inf_contact_form in oldinstance.inf_contact_form.all():
            inf_contact_form.pk = None
            inf_contact_form.plugin = self
            inf_contact_form.save()

class InfContactFormAgreement(models.Model):
    inf_contact_form = models.ForeignKey(InfContactForm, related_name="inf_contact_form")
    agreement = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The "InfContactFormAgreement" model is then used as stacked inline in "InfContactForm" plugin form.

Like it is written in docs, there is also copy_relations() method but when the page is published, nothing happens. When I get back again to edit mode  InfContactFormAgreement is doubled every time I do it.

Here is also my cms_plugins.py file:

```
class PluginInfContactForm(CMSPluginBase):
    render_template = '_contact_form.html'
    name = name1
    model = InfContactForm
    require_parent = False
    inlines = [AgreementStackedInline, ]

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context['instance'] = instance
        context = super(PluginInfContactForm, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        agreements = instance.inf_contact_form.all()
        context.update({
            'agreements': agreements,
        })
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(PluginInfContactForm)
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
inf_contact_form.plugin = self
```

you should use:

```
inf_contact_form.inf_contact_form = self
```

and the resulting code should look like this:

```
def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
    self.inf_contact_form.all().delete()
    for inf_contact_form in oldinstance.inf_contact_form.all():
        inf_contact_form.pk = None
        inf_contact_form.inf_contact_form = self
        inf_contact_form.save()
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, the only difference being that my many-to-many relationship was not in a plugin, but an extension (PageExtension).
In my case, @Dariusz solution did not work, and I had to update the implicit "inbetween" model that exists between the Extension model and the Associated model.

My solution (the key being the "through"):

```
class Extension(PageExtension):
    tags_regions = models.ManyToManyField(Region, related_name="articles", blank=True)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        for region_tag in oldinstance.tags_regions.through.objects.filter(extension=oldinstance):
            region_tag.extension = self
            region_tag.save()
```